# Winforms Button Right-Click visual feedback (Show button in pushed state)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, right-click

The default winforms Button control only draws itself in a "clicked state" when the user left clicks the button. I need the Button control to draw itself in the clicked state regardless of it was left clicked or right clicked. How would I accomplish this?

More specifically, I know I will need to derive a control from Button which extends the functionality, but I have no experience in extending functionality of winforms controls or drawing in GDI+. So I'm a little dumbfounded on what exactly I'll need to do once in there.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: but note that this behavior is against the Windows styles consistency...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard button control sets the button in down and pressed mode using a private `SetFlag` method. You can do it yourself too. I did it in following code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SetPushed(true);
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SetPushed(false);
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        Invalidate();
    }
    private void SetPushed(bool value)
    {
        var setFlag = typeof(ButtonBase).GetMethod("SetFlag", 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if(setFlag != null)
        {
            setFlag.Invoke(this, new object[] { 2, value });
            setFlag.Invoke(this, new object[] { 4, value });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might break in future versions of the framework.

Comment: @Maarten Maybe but less likely. Many things which are based on reflection can break in future versions. But the feature has been the same at least from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.6.2. I'm not sure about .NET 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: @Maarten As another option you can rely on painting the control yourself using  `ButtonRenderer`  or `VisualStyleRenderer`.